# How can I rename label with another class attribute?

Tags: swift2

So, here is the part of class `OnboardingViewController`, where declared and initialized `reviewConsentStep`.

```
class OnboardingViewController: UIViewController {
// MARK: IB actions

@IBAction func joinButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let consentDocument = ConsentDocument()
    let consentStep = ORKVisualConsentStep(identifier: "VisualConsentStep", document: consentDocument)

    let healthDataStep = HealthDataStep(identifier: "Health")

    let signature = consentDocument.signatures!.first!

    let reviewConsentStep = ORKConsentReviewStep(identifier: "ConsentReviewStep", signature: signature, inDocument: consentDocument)

    reviewConsentStep.text = "Review the consent form."
    reviewConsentStep.reasonForConsent = "Consent to join the Developer Health Research Study."

    let passcodeStep = ORKPasscodeStep(identifier: "Passcode")
    passcodeStep.text = "Now you will create a passcode to identify yourself to the app and protect access to information you've entered."

    let completionStep = ORKCompletionStep(identifier: "CompletionStep")
    completionStep.title = "Welcome aboard."
    completionStep.text = "Thank you for joining this study."

    let orderedTask = ORKOrderedTask(identifier: "Join", steps: [consentStep, reviewConsentStep, healthDataStep, passcodeStep, completionStep])
    let taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: orderedTask, taskRunUUID: nil)
    taskViewController.delegate = self

    presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to use `reviewConsentStep.signature?.givenName` and `reviewConsentStep.signature?.familyName` here:

```
@IBOutlet var applicationNameLabel: UILabel!    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    applicationNameLabel.text = reviewConsentStep.signature?.givenName/////////... here
```

If it possible, please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Is your question about how to unwrap an optional? Or how to combine two strings?

Comment: My question is about how can I use the data from another class.
ORKVisualConsentStep class has a reviewConsentStep and I want to use it for rename a label in main.storyboard

Comment: You can set a property and pass the `ORKVisualConsentStep` to other objects as needed. Right now `consentStep` goes out of scope when `joinButtonTapped` returns. So you could either store it, or you can pull it out of `taskViewController`'s `task`'s first step.

Comment: This is my question. What property should I set, how can I do it and where should I do it?

Comment: Make a new one on your view controller. Call it whatever you want. Pass the consent step to the new view controller before presenting it.